Launching apps in the Android emulator hangs at "[monodroid-debug] Trying to initialize the debugger with options"
This problem is related to Visual Studio 2022, all updates installed.
Launching any app of any MAUI project in the Android emulator hangs at [monodroid-debug] Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=10.0.2.2:64294,embedding=1,timeout=1724325932
It makes no difference if the project has break points or not.
The launch of the app gets stuck indefinitely at the blue splash screen with the white .NET text in the middle or some times at a blue screen without any text in it.
Also if I hit the "Stop Debugging" button the cursor turns to busy and then this error message appears in a modal window:

The debugger was unable to terminate one or more processes:
[N/A] Mono: The debugger is still attaching to the process or the process is not currently executing the type of code selected for debugging.
The debugger may be unstable now. It is recommended that you save all
your files and exit."

If I close the modal message the cursor returns to busy for a while and then Visual Studio stops trying to launch the app with the app remaining stuck at the same screen in the emulator.
The only way out is to close the Android emulator.
Deploying the project without debugging works fine.
edit:
I tried reinstalling VS, but that had no effect.
What partially worked is:

Going to Tools > Android SDK Manager > Tools tab > Android Emulator. Then I unchecked the Android Emulator in order to uninstall it and checked it again in order to reinstall it.
Going to Tools > Android Device Manager and then deleting and creating a new device.

I'm not 100% sure if both steps were needed, as I can't recall for sure if a tried to deploy a project after step 1.
Anyway, either only step 1 or maybe both steps gave a temporary solution to the debugging issue.
And I say temporary because even though at first the app launched the debugger didn't stop execution at certain break points and after a few tries the same issue arose with app launch hanging at "[monodroid-debug] Trying to initialize the debugger with options".
What I have to add is that the issues with the debugger seems to start when I disable both Mobile data and Wi-Fi, because I am trying to test code relevant to handling Internet connection exceptions.

Did you try to update the Visual Studio or reinstall it?

I have all the updates installed. Didn't try to remove it and then reinstall it.

Edited my question and added more details. It seems that the issues with the debugger start when I disable the Internet connection of the emulator.

You mean if you don't disable the simulator's internet connection, the simulator can run the project fine?

Yes, that's exactly what happens. If the emulators Internet is disabled the debugger stops working.

I reproduced your problem. After I turned off wifi and mobile data on my Android emulator, it was stuck on the blue startup screen when starting the project.
I found this is a bug on MAUI Github(Starting the debugger with WiFi and Mobile Data turned off crashes). Even though it has been closed, the problem is still unsolved. You can repost this issue on github.
As a workaround, you can try to use .NET CLI (Command Line Interface) to run the project. Although this cannot debug the program through breakpoint, it can at least make the project run normally.
The specific steps:

Install .NET MAUI workload with the dotnet CLI in Command Prompt：


dotnet workload install maui


Start your Android simulator and run the program with the following command(You need to adjust the path and project name to yours).


dotnet build ./source./repos./MauiApp14 -t:run -f net8.0-android


Fortunately, I don't need a workaround. I was trying to debug a piece of code that was managing the loss of Internet connection.
I took another approach in my code that works fine and no debugging is needed.

how did you solve it? you can post it as the answer.

As I said in my previous message I didn't solve it. I just altered the code I was trying to debug and fortunately the new version of my code worked, so I didn't need debugging it anymore.

OK, congratulations, at least the problem has been avoided
